# get chrome app console logs in chrome os debug log

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I've got a chrome app with several isolated layers (webviews, iframes), all those layers are logging some debugging stuff to console with console.log().

I managed to get all console logs inside a chrome debug log when launching chrome on mac os with `--enable-logging --v=1` flags.

The problem is I can't get all the console.logs when running the app in chrome os. For chrome os debugging I wrote the following into `/etc/chrome_dev.conf` file:

```
CHROME_LOG_FILE=/tmp/chrome_debug.log
--enable-logging --v=1
```

So I expect pretty much the same logs as I get when running chrome app on mac os, but I do not see any console.logs in `/tmp/chrome_debug.log`.

Would appreciate any advice how to get my app console.logs in chrome debug log on chrome os

Comment: If it's working on mac OS and not in Chrome OS, maybe you're looking at the wrong path. It says in [Chrome browser debug logs](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271282?hl=en) that default directory varies based on OS. in Chrome OS it's in [/home/chronos](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#Chrome-OS)

Comment: yes, but I specify the exact file to write log to with CHROME_LOG_FILE variable and I do get some operational logs in specified file. But no console.log from apps

Answer (score 0):

Please read the comments in the `/etc/chrome_dev.conf` file, particularly this one at the top:

```
# This file may be modified to make local changes to the environment and command
# line that session_manager uses to run Chrome. It contains one directive per
# line, with the following forms available:
```

That means your `--enable-logging --v=1` is incorrect because you put two options on one line instead of one option per line.